# how to align Save button right side in form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is HTML document, I am using BootStrap4 in my angular application, I want to right-align the SAVE button under the second form in the same row, I am using col-6 for dividing div container for two forms in the same row but problem is that I did try bootstrap classes, also  CSS align property but the problem is still same

```
  <div class="container-fluid bgstyle">
      <div class="container pt-2 pb-2 cntnr">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="align-center col-6  ">
            <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">
              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <label for="file" class="col-sm-10 form-control">Choose profile picture</label>
                  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/* " (change)="selectedFile($event)"
                    class="border-left-0 pl-2 pr-2 form-control mr-2px" formControlName="pic">
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                    placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                    placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                    formControlName="dob">
                </p>
              </div>

              
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">
            <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">


              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                    placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                    placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                    formControlName="dob">
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                    formCotrolName="password">
                </p>
              </div>
                
                
                    <div class=" input-group text-white text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "style="float:right">Save Records </button> 
             </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->

how can i align "save button" to the right side of the form 
Here is my component.html file structure

 

> Updated
<div class="container-fluid bgstyle">
  <div class="container pt-2 pb-2 cntnr">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="align-center col-6  ">
        <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <label for="file" class="col-sm-10 form-control">Choose profile picture</label>
              <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/* " (change)="selectedFile($event)"
                class="border-left-0 pl-2 pr-2 form-control mr-2px" formControlName="pic">
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                formControlName="dob">
            </p>
          </div>

          
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6">
        <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">


          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                formControlName="dob">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                formCotrolName="password">
            </p>
          </div>
            
            
                <div class=" input-group text-white text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "style="float:right">Save Records </button> 
         </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

i want to align this button right side under the second form

Comment: and one thing more , i can get both values in same form formBuilder group in  controller ?

Comment: This has nothing to Angular, just pure styling

Comment: @mpro yeah you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code using float-right:

```html
<div class="container-fluid bgstyle">
  <div class="container pt-2 pb-2 cntnr">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="align-center col-6  ">
        <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <label for="file" class="col-sm-10 form-control">Choose profile picture</label>
              <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/* " (change)="selectedFile($event)"
                class="border-left-0 pl-2 pr-2 form-control mr-2px" formControlName="pic">
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                formControlName="dob">
            </p>
          </div>


        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6">
        <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">


          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                formControlName="dob">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                formCotrolName="password">
            </p>
          </div>


                <div class=" input-group text-white text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "style="float:right">Save Records </button> 
         </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

how can i align "save button" to the right side of the form 
Here is my component.html file structure

> Updated

```
<div class="container-fluid bgstyle">
  <div class="container pt-2 pb-2 cntnr">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="align-center col-6  ">
        <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <label for="file" class="col-sm-10 form-control">Choose profile picture</label>
              <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/* " (change)="selectedFile($event)"
                class="border-left-0 pl-2 pr-2 form-control mr-2px" formControlName="pic">
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                formControlName="dob">
            </p>
          </div>


        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6">
        <form [formGroup]="teacherform" class="pt-2 pb-2 ">


          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="FirstName"
                placeholder="Teacher ID" formControlName="id">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Teacher Name" formControlName="name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="username" aria-describedby="username"
                placeholder="Designation" formControlName="designation">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x  fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control " id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
                formControlName="dob">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <p class="input-group">
              <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                formCotrolName="password">
            </p>
          </div>


                <div class="text-white text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "style="float:right">Save Records </button> 
         </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i don't want to float right complete form just SAVE Button

Comment: I have edited my answer please check. and you add to forget finish double quote for your first col-6 class.

Comment: yeah thanks i forgot ,  yeah i saw updated , but unfortunately i don't know why not working , now i updated my question with complete code

Comment: Its because of your input-group class of button's parent div. remove it and it will work fine. i have update my answer.

Comment: Yeah Thanks i did  identify it myself surely this was error :-) thanks for your effort

Comment: Unfortunately i can't upvote for you because my reputation is 13

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="float: right"` to align to your button to the rightmost of the form.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right">Save Records</button>
```

If you want to mention the pixel, you can use `margin-left: some px`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 100px">Save Records</button>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-c6v5yf)**

Comment: this does work only with button but i want to use it in grid system and then end of the second form , i am updating my question with complete code

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

1. By using bootstrap class

   ```
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Save Records</button>
   ```
2. By using style attribute

   `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right">Save Records</button>`

Comment: A *style **tag*** looks like this: `<style>`.

Comment: my mistake, not style tag it should be attribute

Comment: It is working, I have checked it on codepen and then only I have posted.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth sir please check now complete code

Answer (score 0):

place the button in a div and class name should be text-right in Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class ="container-fluid">
<div class ="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter">
            <div class="text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Save Records        </button> 
            </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This is not working :-( i think this is issue of  two forms in one row ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem was Here**

```
<div class=" input-group text-white text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "style="float:right">Save 
           Records </button>
```

> i was using input-group class now its fine without input group

```
<div class="  text-white text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "style="float:right">Save 
               Records </button> 

</div>
```

Thanks to Every contributor :-)